# iOS DeviceCheck API - Will the token remain same if user uninstall the app

Tags: ios

We want to prevent user from creating multiple profiles on same device. 
For this we first tried IDFA but IDFA can be reset anytime from Settings. 
Then we found [DeviceCheck](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck) that states:

> identifying Access per-device, per-developer data that your associated
>   server can use in its business logic

According to this we get to set two bits per device and a token for server to server verification. Now the question is:

If user uninstalls the app and installs again. will the token remain same?
How would we detect user isn't creating multiple Profiles on same device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Device Check is the best solution for what you are trying to achieve. The advertising ID can be turned off and reset, and the [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier] will be reset once the user uninstalls all app from a given developer.

Device Check is the solution Apple has proposed to check whether a device has redeemed an offer, created a previous profile, or simply to check whether the device is an authentic Apple device.

It requires the use of a server to communicate with Apple servers to validate a client generated token. You get two bits you can set. Those two bits are connected to your developer profile, not two bits per app.

Answer (score 1):

[keychain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services) is the place where you can store users data securely. Storing data in keychain has one more advantage — in a case when the user decides to remove the app from the device and then he decides to install it again, the data is still saved.

Comment: Thanks for referring to keychain. but I would also like to know more about DeviceCheck APi

Comment: `devicecheck` is can use as per device, in keychain you can share data between your applications on that device.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this by storing a value in the `Keychain`. It will persist even if the app is deleted and thus you can tell if the app is a new install or a reinstall. So if a value is there in your keychain it is a reinstall otherwise its a fresh install.

Comment: Thanks for referring to keychain. but I would also like to know more about DeviceCheck APi

Comment: @SahilManchanda: i think it retains on reinstall also. The same is mentioned in the link
https://medium.com/the-traveled-ios-developers-guide/devicecheck-6f3eafac60e5

Comment: As of iOS 10 Keychain data stored by an app will get reset when the user deletes the app. Apple is very adamant about apps not leaving any traces when the user deletes them from the device. DeviceCheck is the best solution right now for checking whether the user has redeemed an offer although it is only available on iOS 11+